k8s pods on different EKS nodes not getting traffic
I have eks cluster with two nodes, I have four k8s services deployed in the cluster, two of them are in node-1 and the other two in node-2. I have have a Kong api gateway in front of these k8s services. My problem is after every restart of the Kong api-gateway deployment, I'm only able to direct traffic to pods on any one node and not both. What could I be doing wrong. Appreciate any help, thanks!

The issue was that I did not have AWS VPC CNI installed on my k8s cluster. Once this plugin was added the pods were able to communicate between nodes.
